# Can't get the values from multiple select with $_GET request

Tags: php, mysql, get, multiple-select

I'd like some help please.

I'm sending with a GET request from a multiple select field the selected values to my proccess page (archive.php)

```
<form id="form1" class="four columns" action="archive.php" method="get" name="form1">
<select id="select2" multiple="multiple" name="location[]">
<option value="103001000">value1</option>
<option value="103002000">value2</option>
<option value="103003000">value3</option>
<option value="103004000">value4</option>
</select>
```

I get the selected locations on my url like this

```
location[]=103002000&location[]=103003000
```

and in the archive.php I'm trying to fetch data from the database like this

```
if (( isset($_GET['location']) && !empty($_GET['location']) )) {
    die(var_dump($_GET['location'])); // the var_dump doesn't return an array at all
    $loc = implode(', ', $_GET['location']);

    $sql="SELECT  * FROM locations WHERE AreaID IN (". $loc.")";
}
```

but I'm getting the following error: Error: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: change name = 'location' and try.

Comment: I think each items in your loc array need to be surrounded by quotes :     `$loc = implode('\', \'', $_GET['location']);` then `$sql="SELECT  * FROM locations WHERE AreaID IN ('". $loc."')";` but you need to escape quotes too if there are in any items.

Comment: @Rubik: Doesn't work. Its weird that I got the selected values on my url and the die() I used to dump my $_GET['location'] array dosn't show anything..

Comment: @Ayyanar G Where do you mean to change the name? in my <select>?

Comment: The `var_dump` inside the die command will let it look like it is empty.
This function is an echo command and does not provide a string. Therefor nothing will be displayed, because the `die` prevents that.

Do the `var_dump` before the `die` and you will see the actual values. Please update the question with that result info

Comment: I still returns the Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' error

Comment: what code you use to excute sql?

Comment: The one inside the if ( isset($_GET['location']) ) statement above

Comment: try REQUEST instead of GET

Comment: did you any other value in GET like text,checkbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with as below it might be simple

```
 if (( isset($_GET['location']) && !empty($_GET['location']) )) {
        die(var_dump($_GET['location'])); // the var_dump doesn't return an array at all
        //$loc = implode(', ', $_GET['location']);
        $_GET['location'] = array('first'=>'loc1','second'=>'loc2','third'=>'loc3');
        $loc = implode('","', $_GET['location']);
        $loc ='"'.$loc.'"';

        $sql='SELECT  * FROM locations WHERE AreaID IN ('.$loc.')';
        echo $sql;
    }
```

> result query

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE AreaID IN ("loc1","loc2","loc3")
```